# Finding multiple XML elements using Element Tree and XPath

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, elementtree

I am quite new to Python and am trying to extract multiple fields from an XML file containing metadata on a large numbers of research articles using Element Tree. While I am able to get the fields I want separately using two different methods (Element Tree and XPath - shown below) what I need is a way to combine these into one piece of code that will return article IDs and corresponding funding info for all my articles.

Update:

My desired output for the example would be:
"20.2019/ABC-2019-0111,
This work was supported by the NIH"

Ideally the data for each article would be separated by a special character that I could use to delimit my results in Excel.

I haven't used lxml before but am happy to try whatever works best..

XML example:

```
<root>
  <article>
    <front>
     <article-meta>
      <article-id pub-id-type="publisher-id">ABC-2019-0111</article-id>
      <article-id pub-id-type="doi">20.2019/ABC-2019-0111</article-id>
       <article-categories>
        <subj-group subj-group-type="heading">
        <subject>Science</subject>
        </subj-group>
       </article-categories> 
     </article-meta> 
      <body>
        <back>
          <sec id="sec7" sec-type="funding">
            <title>Funding</title>
            <p>This work was supported by the NIH</p>
          </sec>
        </back>
      </body>
    </front>
  </article>
</root>


to get article IDs:
for elem in tree.iter(tag='article-id'): print(elem.text)

to get funding info:
doc = ET.parse('articles.xml')
print([p.text for p in doc.findall('.//sec[@sec-type="funding"]/p')])
```

Comment: What would the desired output look like for the example XML? Also, are you restricted to ElementTree or can you use lxml?

Comment: *"a way to combine these into one piece of code"*: **First** get all  `<article>...</article>` Elements then `loop` and get what you need from every `Element`.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand your explanation, but I had initially tried to get IDs and store these as dictionary keys and then get the funding info and store these as values. However, not every article xml has funding info so the key value pairs do not correspond. What i'm looking to do is to get both the ID and funding info for one article and then move on to the next article and so forth.